# Is it possible to make a magnetic box that will compensate Earth gravity allowing magnetic objects inside to fly on orbits like in space?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, magnetic-fields, solar-system, models

Is it possible to simulate solar system using magnetic spheres and some kind of box that will compensate the Earth gravity by magnetic force?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive please. The question does not make sense.

Comment: How to do it?
I need a transparent box with flying objects inside

Comment: You cannot shield gravity.

Comment: You could try a vertically oriented nearly homogenous magnetic field (using coils) and a single electrically charged planet hanging and swinging like a pendulum. The lorentz force would make it go in a circle but you'd probably have to make the chamber vacuum to have it last for any real length of time.

Comment: You might have better luck using air flow and ping pong ball like planets https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D-JV7MGpOwiI&ved=2ahUKEwjDxv_kka30AhX3LTQIHfsACu0Qo7QBegQIBhAF&usg=AOvVaw0fQpfZbKzDlG1TYoah6Z_o

Comment: @Markoul11 I can't shield the gravity but I can create the force equal and opposite directed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a simulated solar system using magnets instead of gravity.  Your plan is to use magnetism as the attracting force, and then centrifugal force of planets spinning around the sun to offset and keep the planets in orbit at the appropriate distance.   Is this what you want?

If so, it would be extremely difficult, if not impossible.  First, magnets have a very short range of influence.  So once you moved your planets more than a few centimeters away, there would be no magnetic force at all.  Second, the real planets orbit the sun in an elliptical orbit, not just a circle, so the magnetic force between the sun and planet would not be the same at all points during the orbit.  Third, the different distances between the sun and the planets would be impossible to work with given the different sizes of the planets. Finally, the centrifugal force necessary to stop the planets from falling into the sun would be extreme, so they would be wiping around the sun too fast to enjoy.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a model of a solar system in a transparent box.  There are devices which can levitate magnetic spheres, but generally these involve complex field configurations which offer only one location for a stable equilibrium at a small height. You might consider a simulation on a flat surface.  My wife has a decorative piece which features miniature figures that appear to be skating at random on a small (plastic) pond. They are being dragged around by moving magnets beneath the surface.  Your solar system could be animated in a similar manner. Come to think of it, you might use a moving electromagnet above each sphere. Each  magnet wold need a sensor to determine the distance down to its sphere and a control circuit to hold that distance constant. The top of the box would be opaque to hide this mechanism.